# How to write CSS that is only effective in non-IE, non-Edge browsers?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am trying to write CSS that is only applicable to 'desktop' screen sizes, but only if the page is viewed from a non-IE and non-Edge browsers. What I already have:

`@media only screen and (min-width: 981px) /* and XXX */`

The 'XXX' above is the part where I'm hoping to receive help for. From browsing around I already gathered that this is the clause for confirming the presence of  IE: `@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none)`, and this is the clause for conforming Edge: `@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto)`. However I am at loss with the correct CSS to use, to 'concatenate' and 'negate' these two.

Comment: Edge is using -webkit so it will be hard to negate, I would suggest to detect the browser and supply the stylesheet, depending upon the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) to create the expression, like this:

```css
@supports not (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
    /*Non-Edge and Non-IE  style*/
    body {
        background-color: azure;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The reference you attached was helpful. However I am still trying to figure out how to 'AND' the two clauses together, ie. @media AND @support. I have also tried embedding, ie. ```@support not (-ms-ime-align:auto) {  @media only screen and (min-width: 981px) {} }```

Comment: You could use the `@media` and `@support` together, it also works well, please refer to [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7bhy0xqd/).